# Download Plugin(Uploaded Wordpress Plugin) from linux server using FTP (Filezilla)

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, wamp, whitespace

I am Hosting Server with Linux. I uploaded the wordpress plugin from the admin settings. After that i download that plugin from the plugin folder through ftp(Filezilla). When i view the code after downloading it getting too many whitespace happen. I am not sure why this should happen. I Create the Plugin from the wamp server of localhost and upload that plugin to the live server of linux. Is the Problem Arise creating code from wamp machine upload to the linux machine.

Any Suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Maybe you should ask here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will post this thread there. . .

Comment: It is probably best to install the plugin rather than copy it as the install may well do something that a copy woudl not do.